# Взлом или что это?

Tags: взлом

я не знаю где и у кого можно спросить, поэтому обращаюсь за помощью именно сюда... 
У меня есть подозрения, что взломан компьютер 
Дело в том, что "Я" заходила  с разных IP-адресов со своего домашнего пк
У меня, и у всей семьи ВСЕ соц.сети взломаны( Лайки,  которые взялись не понятно откуда, подписки и рассылки)
Вчера я  завершила все сессии входа и сменила все пароли, но сегодня всё снова повторилось)
В браузере при  открытии одной нужной вкладки,   открываются ещё несколько  автоматически! (реклама, ставки) Также рекламные баннеры на рабочем столе, которые  я закрываю, но сразу же появляются новые.
 OC Windows 7, Антивирус Kaspersky  включён, обнаружил 2 вируса и они были удалены (Показывает всё норм, но что-то всё равно не чисто) 
Что мне делать?

Comment: Систему переустанавливать.

Comment: ... а потом наконец-то начать использовать двухфакторную аутентификацию.

Comment: Вы не используете VPN?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в другом браузере или в режиме инкогнито, если там все ок, скорее установили зловредное расширение в браузер.

Comment: Антивирус не даёт манипулировать вашей операционной системой, все остальное может происходить с вашего согласия нажав на чего либо ))))
В вашем случаи я думаю что Вы или кто-то использовали сервисы накруток в соц сетях и ваши акканты стали обычными ботами))) Если вы сменили пароли я думаю через некоторое время всё это прекратится т.к. сервис больше не сможет использовать COOKIE